# Transform event list dataframe in adjacency dataframe

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix, topic-modeling, sna

I have a df in which every columns represent an event and in cells there are the individuals, like this:

```
df=data.frame(topic1=c("a", "b","c", "d"), topic2=c("e","f", "g", "a"), topic3=c("b","c","g","h"))
```

I need to transform it in adjacency df, like this:

```
        topic1 topic2   topic3
   a    1      1        0
   b    1      0        1
   c    1      0        1
   d    1      0        0
   e    0      1        0
   f    0      1        0
   g    0      1        1
   h    0      0        1
```

THX!

Comment: You can do `table(stack(df))`.

Comment: try lvl=unique(unlist(df)) ; apply(df,2,function(i)table(factor(i,levels=lvl))) ?

Comment: THX @StupidWolf!!! It run :)

Comment: Great! are you using it for igraph? if so, there is a function in it to convert data frames to graphs

Comment: sorry @StupidWolf I'm using this code with another data but it return this message:  Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : 
  factor level [61] is duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form `levs` containing the levels in sorted order and then for each column of `df` determine which levs are in it.  This gives a logical matrix which we can convert to numeric using `+`.

```
levs <- sort(unique(unlist(df)))   # a b c d e f g h
+ sapply(df, function(x) levs %in% x)
```

giving:

```
     topic1 topic2 topic3
[1,]      1      1      0
[2,]      1      0      1
[3,]      1      0      1
[4,]      1      0      0
[5,]      0      1      0
[6,]      0      1      0
[7,]      0      1      1
[8,]      0      0      1
```

The last line could be written even more compactly as:

```
+ sapply(df, `%in%`, x = levs)
```